# Create table from Google Sheet with multi line headings

Tags: google-bigquery

I have been creating BigQuery tables from Google Sheets via the BQ console GUI. This has been working well, but I am now trying to import a file with multiple heading lines and I don't know how to go about it.

[image: A simple example of what I am trying to import]

If I try to auto detect schema and skip the first 2 columns I get the error **Failed to create table: Duplicate column names: 'Date'.**

If I try and mannually create the schema, similar to below. Then the import works but when I go to query the records I get the error **Unsupported field type: RECORD**

```
 [
  {
    "name": "SubjectName",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
  },
  {
    "name": "SubjectCode",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
  },
  {
    "name": "Class1",
    "type": "RECORD",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "Date",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      },
      {
        "name": "Tutor",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Class2",
    "type": "RECORD",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "Date",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      },
      {
        "name": "Tutor",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Class3",
    "type": "RECORD",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "Date",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      },
      {
        "name": "Tutor",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is there any way to import a google sheet with multiple headings via the BQ Console gui?

Comment: `RECORD` data type is [not supported](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-execution-error-code#properties) in google sheets. You can create a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) for this.

Comment: Thanks for the information @AnjelaB. So just to confirm, there is no way to import multi level headings from google sheets?

Comment: For this scenario, you need to address first the data type to proceed.